# Where to store meta information for elasticsearch clients

Tags: elasticsearch

For our elasticsearch clients we have to provide labeling, validation, etc. information.
E.g. there is a type customer with the field name.

Field name should be labeled in the GUI of the clients with 'Name:', should be mandatory and has maximum length of 30 characters.

These meta info should be not document specific. All documents of type customer have the same labeling, validation, etc. for the particular field.

The intention is that clients should generate their gui dynamically at runtime from these information. Not the whole gui, but for e.g. textfields and its validation

Where is the best place to store such information. In the type mapping of customer or a separate view/gui type?

Are there any best practices how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately it is not possible to put the info into the type mapping (JSON schema). So create a new type config and an instance (document) of this config.
The config consists of key/value pairs. The id of the indexed config is also the version. Incompatible changes of config would be indexed with an higher id.

The config JSON schema:

```
{
    "config":{
        "properties":{
            "property":{
                "properties":{
                    "key":{
                        "type":"string"
                    },
                    "value":{
                        "type":"string"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Sample config instance/document:

```
{
    "property": [
        {"key":"customer.label", "value":"Customer"},
        {"key":"customer.minLength", "value":"3"},
        {"key":"customer.maxLength", "value":"20"},

        {"key":"product.1234.price.label", "value":"Price"},
        {"key":"product.1234.price.currency", "value":"Dollar"}
    ]     
}
```